# Trying to find one of my own (deleted?) questions

Tags: discussion, search

About 1.5 month back I posted a question about a strange problem concerning the connection to my smartphone through my router.

I'm trying to find it going through my questions, "all actions" and my other Stack Exchange communities I could have used for the question. However I can not find it.

Could it have been deleted or something similar?

Comment: I'm not sure what the timeframe of "recent" is, but if you go to your dedicated questions or answers tab on your user page, there is a link at the bottom to show recent deleted ones.

Comment: @fixer1234 Not more then a few weeks, the question in question isn't there. Thanks for the suggestion! oh, nice rhyme... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [its this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1366752/no-connection-between-devices-on-the-same-wlan-access-point). It got roombaed - deleted by the system for being zero score, zero answer.

Comment: that's it, thanks. Is it possible to view my question that have been deleted? They don't show up in my question list.

Comment: If you had a link, or if was recent, yes - after a while, I don't think so. That said - chances are, if you asked nicely, a mod will help. Like now!